# Change cell styles from one style to another

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to change all cells in a workbook with a particular style to another, and then remove the old style.

I have code which works in isolation, but when it is applied to a large workbook with a large used range on each sheet it can take a long time or crash.

```
Sub ChngStyle()

Dim sty1 As String: sty1 = "Total"
Dim sty2 As String: sty2 = "From"
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim cell As Range

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        For Each cell In ws.UsedRange
            If cell.style = sty1 Then
                Application.Goto cell
                On Error Resume Next
                cell.style = sty2
            End If
        Next cell
    Next ws

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    MsgBox "Done"
    ActiveWorkbook.Styles(sty1).Delete

End Sub
```

Is there a way to use FIND/FINDFORMAT/something else for a particular style to only target the cells with that style?

Is there a more efficient way of seeing whether the code needs to run on the worksheet before looping through the entire used range?

Comment: Since you turned `Application.ScreenUpdating` off, you should not need `Application.Goto`, as the main purpose of that is to visibly scroll to a range. Per the [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.goto), that function is adding each cell range to a back-stack of changes for an undo process, which is costing you a lot of cycles.  `On Error Resume Next` is also doing nothing except to potentially hide other issues.

Comment: Great thank you - I've made that change. It's still a little slow though as it needs to check through every cell in the used range for every sheet, is there anything that can avoid that (similar to xlspecialcells perhaps?)